# How do I configure a local Chocolatey repository?

Tags: chocolatey

I'm trying to learn about Chocolatey by setting up a local repository on my machine (`c:\ChocolateyLocal\`).  However, I can't seem to add the folder as a source.  I've tried using the command line and ChocolateyGui, and I get the same error:

> Failed to query source.

The paths I've tried are (all with and without trailing `\`):

- `c:\ChocolateyLocal`
- `file://localhost/c/ChocolateyLocal` (my C-drive is shared privately for dev purposes, don't judge me)
- `file:///C:/chocolateylocal`
- `\\localhost\c\ChocolateyLocal`
- `http://localhost/c/chocolateylocal`

I'm using the latest Chocolatey (v0.9.9.11).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What version of Chocolatey are you using?

`choco source add -n name -s location`

https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CommandsSources

A side note - you may also need at least 1 package in there.

Comment: It seems this works on the command line, but it's not working in the ChocolateyGUI app.

Comment: Sounds like a followup for the ChocolateyGUI folks

Comment: When you add `-n name` does this imply that the `location` is a single internalised package? Or can the source be a directory with multiple internalised packages?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `-n` or `--name="'name of source'"` implies the name of the source that you are adding.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is a disconnect between ChocolateyGUI and Chocolatey, in terms of the sources that are defined.  This is a known issue, which is being tracked on this [issue](https://github.com/chocolatey/ChocolateyGUI/issues/253).  There was some initial work to reconcile these two sources configuration files in this [pull request](https://github.com/chocolatey/ChocolateyGUI/pull/257), but that hasn't been pulled in yet.  This is due to the fact that we are moving ChocolateyGUI to use the Chocolatey Library, which means they will be configured out of the box.  This work is still on going though.

For now, you can add Sources into ChocolateyGUI by following the instructions in this [wiki article](https://github.com/chocolatey/ChocolateyGUI/wiki/How-to-add-a-new-custom-source).  The instructions are copied below as well:

1. Open ChocolateyGUI
2. Click the ***"settings"*** button at the top right of the screen
3. Click Sources
4. Enter the Name for the new Source
5. Enter the Url for the new Source
6. Click the ***"add source"*** button

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's interesting.  I thought it was merely a UI shell around the command line structure.  Much like tortoiseHg.

Comment: @gregsdennis that is certainly the intention, and that will be the case once we fully take the dependency on the Chocolatey Library.  For now, because we are talking to the oData Endpoints directly from within ChocolateyGUI, the sources have to be managed separately.